# Complex Line Integral along the unit circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

> Show that: 
>   $$\oint_\gamma\frac{1}{z}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2n}\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i\cdot\binom{2n}{n},\quad\text{while
> > }\gamma=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,|z|=1\}\,\,(\text{unit circle})$$

So far I get the integrand (using the Binomial Theorem):
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\oint_\gamma\frac{z^{2k}}{z^{2n+1}}\mathrm dz$$
and changed it a little bit:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\frac{(2n)!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{2\pi i\cdot z^{2k}}{(2n)!z^{2n+1}}$$
by using Cauchy Integral formula we get:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(\binom{2n}{k}\cdot\left(\frac{2\pi i}{(2n)!}\cdot\frac{\partial^{(2n)}}{\partial z^{(2n)}}(z^{2k})\right)\right)$$
and that is where I got stuck.

How do I derive $z^{(2k)} 2n$ times (assuming $n$ is bigger than $k$, the answer would be zero and that is incorrect)? or maybe I done it wrong. Please help!

Comment: For which $m$ is $\int_\gamma z^m\,dz \neq 0$?

Comment: For all m except m=1?

Comment: Not quite. I wrote $\int_\gamma z^m\,dz$, not $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^m}$.

Comment: Okay, I get that when m = -1 it isn't zero.

Comment: Good. Now take a sharp look at your integrands $\dfrac{z^{2k}}{z^{2n+1}}$.

Comment: I get that n must be equal to k in order to get a non-zero value

Comment: Right. But since $n$ is fixed, better say $k$ must be equal to $n$. So, what is the overall result?

Comment: You are a genius my friend :) thx

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer for correcting my error.

Comment: No problem, @Adobe. Thanks for investing a lot of time improving the site.

Comment: this is a nice thread: @Adobe would you like to summarize the above considerations in an answer? It would be helpful

Comment: @Avitus Seems someone already did during my absence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we notice  that 
$$\int_\gamma z^m\,dz = \begin{cases} 2\pi i \quad &\text{if } m=-1 \\ 0 \quad &\text{if }m\ne -1\end{cases}$$
the question boils down to finding the coefficient of $z^{-1}$. Since
$$z^{-1} (z+z^{-1})^{2n}
= z^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} z^k (z^{-1})^{2n-k}
=  \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k} z^{2k-2n-1}$$
the relevant term has $k=n$. Hence the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is $\binom{2n}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach, parametrizing the contour $\gamma$ as $z=e^{i\theta}$

> $$ \oint_\gamma \frac{z^{2k}}{z^{2n+1}}dz= \oint_\gamma {z^{2k-2n-1}}dz=i\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{2i\theta(k-n)}d\theta = \begin{cases} 2\pi i,\quad k=n \\ 0,\quad k\neq n \end{cases}.$$